# How to use the same button(one button) to add items in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

[image: Layout Image]

I created a fragment layout. Now, i want to add data into a database and display into each fragments. I use a pop up menu which is to be share for each fragment. My problem is that how will a single button will add item into a database for the different fragment. Please help!

Here my database operation

```
public class Db_operation_helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String Database_name="database_name";
private static final int Database_version=1;
 private static final String Monday_query=
    "CREATE TABLE "+ UserContract.Time_monday.Mon_tablename+"("+ UserContract.Time_monday.Mon_subject+" TEXT,"+
            UserContract.Time_monday.Mon_instructor+" TEXT,"+ UserContract.Time_monday.Mon_timeone+" TEXT,"+
            UserContract.Time_monday.Mon_timetwo+" TEXT);";
private static final String Tuesday_query=
        "CREATE TABLE "+ UserContract.Time_tuesday.Tue_tablename+"("+ UserContract.Time_tuesday.Tue_subject+" TEXT,"+
                UserContract.Time_tuesday.Tue_instructor+" TEXT,"+ UserContract.Time_tuesday.Tue_timeone+" TEXT,"+
                UserContract.Time_tuesday.Tue_timetwo+" TEXT);";
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Gradebook_Query);
    Log.e("Database Operation", "Table Grade Book Created");
    db.execSQL(Monday_query);
    Log.e("Database Operation", "Table Monday Created");
    db.execSQL(Tuesday_query);
 public void monday_add(String subject,String instructor,String timeone,String timetwo,SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(UserContract.Time_monday.Mon_subject,subject);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.Time_monday.Mon_instructor,instructor);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.Time_monday.Mon_timeone,timeone);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.Time_monday.Mon_timetwo,timetwo);
    db.insert(UserContract.Time_monday.Mon_tablename, null, contentValues);
    Log.e("Database Operation", "One row is inserted into Time Table monday");
}
public void tuesday_add(String subject,String instructor,String timeone,String timetwo,SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(UserContract.Time_tuesday.Tue_subject,subject);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.Time_tuesday.Tue_instructor,instructor);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.Time_tuesday.Tue_timeone,timeone);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.Time_tuesday.Tue_timetwo,timetwo);
    db.insert(UserContract.Time_tuesday.Tue_tablename, null, contentValues);
    Log.e("Database Operation", "One row is inserted into Time Table Tueday");
}
```

Here's the contract class

```
public class UserContract {
public static abstract class  Time_monday{
    public static final String Mon_subject="mon_subject";
    public static final String Mon_instructor="mon_instructor";
    public static final String Mon_timeone="mon_timeone";
    public static final String Mon_timetwo="mon_timetwo";
    public static final String Mon_tablename="mon_tablename";
}
public static abstract class  Time_tuesday{
    public static final String Tue_subject="tue_subject";
    public static final String Tue_instructor="tue_instructor";
    public static final String Tue_timeone="tue_timeone";
    public static final String Tue_timetwo="tue_timetwo";
    public static final String Tue_tablename="tue_tablename";
}}
```

And,this is the pop up window class java

```
public class Popwindow_timetable extends Activity {
EditText Subject, Instructor, Timeone, Timetwo;
Context context=this;
Db_operation_helper db_operation_helper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popwindow);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .650), (int) (height * .4));
    Subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
    Instructor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.instructor);
    Timeone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timeone);
    Timetwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timetwo);
}
public void timetable_add(View view)
{
    String subject=Subject.getText().toString();
    String instructor=Instructor.getText().toString();
    String timeone=Timeone.getText().toString();
    String timetwo=Timetwo.getText().toString();
    db_operation_helper=new Db_operation_helper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase=db_operation_helper.getWritableDatabase();
    db_operation_helper.monday_add(subject,instructor,timeone,timetwo,sqLiteDatabase);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"DATA IS ADDED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db_operation_helper.close();
}
```

}

In this java file, timetable_add() function will be call when the button is click .Here the data is added only to a monday table.But,i want to add data respectively to a fragment.My problem is that when the fragment is swap to another layout the data enter will be added to the another table in a database when the button is click. but i dont know how to implement the code in a button click, to add data into another table of database as the button is share by all the fragment.

Comment: There should a separate class which manage database or data storage. You can create instance of this class in your FragmentActivity and can then use that instance for data post and get

Comment: And If you want to display or change the values concurrently, you can use broadcast receiver or interface for any change in the data will inform the registered receivers about it.

Comment: I already create a database but whenever i add items into a single table only..what i mean is that..i create a different table for each fragment and whenever i go to another fragment layout and click the add button...i data will be added into its respective table of database..i think the button will have some comparison statement..eg if statement ..but i don't know how to implement the coding..correct me if i'm wrong..

Comment: There should be a central data provider which should be accessible from higher prospective like from Activity. And write or read data to it.

Comment: Can you post your database querys please ?

Comment: yes of course, re check the question i have edited and upload my java file.